# jQuery on within each only binds function to final item

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, event-handling, closures

I am trying to bind one function to dynamically created elements, passing different variables to it for each group in the array.  But the code below only binds the function to the final array item:

```
<div id="pbody">My dogs chase cats for canine fun.</div>
<script>
function picturekeywords() {
    $(wops).each(function(index) {
        var $this = this;
        var keyword = this.keywords.split(',');
        $(keyword).each(function() {
            var rex = new RegExp('((\\w|\\b|\'|\"|‘|’|“|”)*' + this + '(\\w|\\b|\'|\"|‘|’|“|”)*)', 'gi');
            $('#pbody').html($('#pbody').html().replace(rex, '<span class="wop">$1</span>'));
        });
        $('.wop').on('mouseenter', {wopobj:$this}, wop);
        $('.wop').attr('class', 'woptrig');
    });
    $('.woptrig .woptrig').each(function() {
        $(this).after($(this).html());
        $(this).remove();
    });
}
picturekeywords();

function wop(event) {
    var wopobj = event.data.wopobj;
    console.log(wopobj.picture);
}

var wops = [{keywords:'dog,canine', picture:'dog.jpg'}, {keywords:'cat,feline', picture:'cat.jpg'}];
</script>
```

The desired result should log the image name for the keyword hovered over.  But it only works for the last.

http://jsbin.com/doyoxu/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

I think it looks like a closure issue, but can't work it out.  Any ideas?

Comment: Not the issue, but those `<html>` tags are horribly misplaced ?

Comment: you are attaching the event handler to all `.wop` elements so the final event handler gets on top, attach the handler to specific `.wop` element and not to all at once using the `.wop` selector

Comment: I thought that by changing the class each time the new iteration would only affect the right elements?  In any case, adding a .each() for the $('.wop').on() yields the same result (see bin).

Comment: What are you attaching a data object to it when  $(this) in the method would be exactly the same thing? The issue is the fact `$('.wop').on('mouseenter', {wopobj:$this}, wop);` is adding a new evenet to everything on over iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka!  The replace function changed the whole text each time, not just matches.  So I split the loop into two, binding all functions last.  Sorted.  :)